# 外部データ読み込みJSのエラーが出た際の通知方法

Tags: javascript

FacebookやTwitterなどのフィードを集めて表示するサービスを利用しています。
https://www.juicer.io/
その統合フィードをFBやTwではなくそのサービスが発効していてwebサイトに埋め込める様になっています。
以下埋め込みコードの例です。

```
<script src="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<ul class="juicer-feed" data-feed-id="xxxxxxxxxxx">......</ul>
```

そのフィードの読み込みに稀にエラーが発生してしまい、そのエラーに気づかないまま数日経ってしまうことがあり、
エラーが発生した場合にメールなどに通知する監視方法がないか探しています。
その様な方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: エラーの種類にもよりますか、読み込みエラーであればlink、scriptタグにonerrorを利用してハンドルするのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。scriptやcssの読み込みは基本的に問題ありませんが、scriptがフィードを読み込む際に読み込めなかった旨のエラーをDevToolのコンソールに出力してくれるのですが、その監視をしたいのです。言葉足らずですみません。